# How to dismiss keyboard on second time selecting first textfield?

Tags: iphone, keyboard-events

I'm trying to dismiss keyboard on textfield did begin editing.
First time selecting that textfield works fine, But in second time after resigning second textfield first textfield doesn't resign keyboard.
I tried hard but not get result

Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set your delegate properly for both the text fields?

Comment: i have set delegate for another purpose so not set for this one

Comment: Can you post sample code? It would greatly help me and others see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Can u explain in detail, what you want to perform...

Comment: I'm doing this if ([txt5 isFirstResponder])
        {
            NSLog(@"textfield 5 firstresponder");
            [txt5 resignFirstResponder]; 
        }
        else if([txt4 isFirstResponder])
        {
             NSLog(@"textfield 4 firstresponder");
            [txt4 resignFirstResponder];
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide keyboard by own method.

For Eg.

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {

     if (sender == txt1) {

       [txt2 becomeFirstResponder];
     }

     else if (sender == txt2) {

       [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
     }
}
```

Bind both of textfields with 'Did End On Exit' method in xib.

After resigning first, it'll focus on 2nd. Then after resigning 2nd, keyboard will be dismissed. you can continue with many textfields in this manner.

It'll work definately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement textField's delegate to all the textFields to your class.

And use this one:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        if (textField == yourTextfield1) {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
```